# JQuery function not working with Python's Bottle

Tags: jquery, python, html, bottle

I am trying to override the default behaviour of the submit button in a HTML form in order to be able to load a JQuery animation before actually kicking the form action.
The JQuery is running correctly when I run the HTML file from the IDE but when I load it from the bottle framework it just skips automatically to the form submission.

Here's what I have:

**Bottle**

```
@route('/')
def root():
    return template('output_template.html', results=False)

@route('/lookup', method='POST')
def lookup():
    '''
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/lookup" method="post" class="col s6">
  <div class="row">
    <h4 class="left-align"> Property Search</h4>
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="POSTCODE" id="postcode" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="postcode">Post code</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves  blue-grey" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Started Form Submission')
        $("#content").hide("slow");
        $("#loading").show();
        delay(4);
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Any ideas on what it's wrong?

Comment: Where does that `delay()` function come from?

Comment: I just put the delay function as a test to make sure the fact that I couldn't see the loading screen was because the next page loaded instantly.

Comment: That function does not exist out of the box in Javascript. Are you sure it is not triggering another error?

Comment: No. The function is working properly when I run it from the IDE (PyCharm to be exact). It just doesn't work when I run it from the Botttle Local Host server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Bottle was not rendering the JQuery script in the bottom of the page. I changed it to the head and it now works correctly.
Thank you a

Answer (score 0):

If your JQuery code is inside an own file, `Bottle` most likely does not know how to serve it, since you only have routes for `'/'` and `'/lookup'`. Take a look at [routing static files](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) in bottle:

```
from bottle import static_file
@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/your/static/files')
```

Don't forget to change the script's location in your HTML header accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However I already have the static server defined and I'm using the JQuery as a script in the same page as the HTML.
I still don't know what's wrong since it works when i run the template from PyCharm